# Map<Long, List<String>> to List of String Lambda by some key

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `HashMap` like `Map<Long, List<String>> map = ....` and

also I have a list of key like `List<Long> keyList = Arrays.asList(1L, 3L, 10L);`

I want to extract the `List<String>` by these `keyList's` and generate a single  `List<String>` using lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `reduce` instead of `flatMap, collect`:

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<Long, List<String>> map = createTestMap();
    final List<Long> keyList = asList(1L, 3L, 10L);
    final List<String> resultList = keyList.stream()
        .map(map::get)
        .map(ArrayList::new)  // need to create new lists not to corrupt the existing ones
        .reduce((left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left;})  // accumulate the list
        .orElse(new ArrayList<>());  // empty list if nothing was found
    System.out.println(resultList);
  }

  private static Map<Long, List<String>> createTestMap() {
    final Map<Long, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    final List<String> oneList = asList("1 love", "1 peace");
    final List<String> threeList = singletonList("3 words");
    final List<String> tenList = emptyList();
    final List<String> ninetyList = singletonList("99 problems");
    map.put(1L, oneList);
    map.put(3L, threeList);
    map.put(10L, tenList);
    map.put(90L, ninetyList);
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly this.

Comment: Even if you copy each element to a new `ArrayList`, this is an abuse of `reduce`. Using a correct [*Mutable reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), is not harder than your `.map(ArrayList::new) .reduce((left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left;}) .orElse(new ArrayList<>())`. You can use either `collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll)` or `.flatMap(List::stream) .collect(Collectors.toList())`, both being simpler, shorter and more efficient than the abuse of `reduce`…

Comment: After reading about Mutable reduction, I also think that it would be more proper to apply `collect`. However, the proposed approach is an alternative, and why could it abuse the `reduce` function?

Comment: An ordinary reduction function should not modify its incoming values. You are fixing this by copying every list into a new `ArrayList` in the preceding `map` step, which is not only very inefficient, but creating a non-obvious dependency between the terminal operation and the preceding intermediate operation. How many readers would understand this dependency without the clarifying comment? Or, in other words, doing the intended thing is not always sufficient to be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
List<String> values = keyList.stream()    // for each key
    .map(map::get)                        // convert keys to their values
    .flatMap(List::stream)                // stream the lists as one stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList());        // as a single list of String
```